# reading app settings as null from App.config

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

I am struggeling reading data from a configuration file, and all the methods online are not working for me...
I have this configuration file (`App.config`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="test" value="testVal"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And this line in my C# code

```
string appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test"];
```

for some reason, appSettings remains null when expected to be testVal.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Put a break point right after that and check the value. I tested same code and getting the value.
If you use web application make sure you put this in web.config and not in the app.config

Comment: I did but nothing is being read from there

Answer (score 0):

Something that may be happening is the App.config isn't being included in the build output. Check the bin folder of your project directory (Debug/Release), and ensure there's a file that matches the namespace of your project with a ".config" extension. You should see, for example:

- YourApp.dll
- YourApp.exe
- YourApp.dll.config (edit this in notepad to verify it contains the
  appsetting values)
- ...

Assuming this is the case and you don't see the config, or it doesn't have the correct values, ensure the App.config file in your project is included in the project itself (not just added manually to the project directory through file explorer).

If it is included and still not working, try deleting and re-creating a new "Application Configuration File" in your project in Visual Studio... that should clear things up (hopefully!). Be sure to save the original app.config contents beforehand when doing this.